# Streaming video server

Tags: video-streaming, debian, webcam

I'm trying to build a live video streaming server that can accept multiple live feeds from several remote webcams (AXIS IP cameras or a USB webcam streaming with MJPG-Streamer) and re-stream them to web clients.

The stream needs to be viewable on a webpage using Internet Explorer and all other major browsers without requiring any third party plugins as I want to make the end result as simple and accessible as possible.

The end service is a free webcam gallery of my local town for potential visitors to browse and view. I currently have a single camera running using a windows box and application streaming from my own home fiber connection but would like to move it to a server in a data center so more viewers can connect without chewing up my home connection. I would like to add more feeds from around the town using IP cameras or RPi's with USB cams attached.

There seems to be lots of streaming servers out there and many ways to stream a single source but I can't find much that will accept multiple IP sources and produce multiple streams.

Ideally I would like to build something on Debian as that is the OS I am most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that there is no any answer in this thread, I would like to present you a possible solution. Although you want to use the Linux-based Debian, but I take it out of your words ("that is the OS I am most comfortable with") that you may have some experience with other operating systems as well.

If so, this tutorial at Dotnetfunda about [how to implement Onvif IP camera service](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3001/how-to-implement-onvif-ip-camera-service-and-rtsp-streaming-to-smartph) can be useful for your purposes. It demonstrates a C#-based solution that enables you to build an ONVIF IP camera server. It shows how to implement RTSP streaming to multiple locations - including remote computers and mobile devices as well.

But, unfortunately it has been built by using this Windows-based [Onvif IP camera software](http://www.camera-sdk.com/). However this SDK also supports [MJPEG streaming](http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_237-how-to-display-mjpeg-camera-stream-in-c-onvif.html), so it may worth to take a look at this solution.

If your issue has already solved or you exclude any Windows-based solution, I apologize for having waste your time.